# how to set styles for a text in the code example

Tags: css

I am very new with CSS and I can't style my code well. How to set "font-size:30px;" for the text "font_30", and "font-size:3px;" for the text "font_3" in the code example?

```
<style>
.cl_30 {font-size:30px;}
.cl_3 {font-size:3px;}
</style>

<div class="cl_30">
<p class="cl_3">font_3</p>
font_30
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is correct and working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is exactly correct. The font-size of `3px` is quite small and easy to glance by, but the text is visible if you look closely.

```html
<style>
  .cl_30 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  .cl_3 {
    font-size: 3px;
  }
</style>

<div class="cl_30">
  <p class="cl_3">font_3</p>
  font_30
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is clear because it has "Run code snippet". Thank you very much.